# Following relationships “backward” TastyPie

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, tastypie

I'm attempting to follow a relationship "backwards" with TastyPie, however I haven't quite managed to. The documentation doesn't really go into much detail and I've tried searching the web to no avail.

I know in Django I could achieve it [like this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/queries/#backwards-related-objects), but how do I achieve the same in TastyPie?

My models.py looks like this:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Gallery(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    created = models.DateField()

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s %s' % (self.name, self.created)

class Painting(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    url = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=800)
    gallery = models.ForeignKey(Gallery, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    published = models.DateField()

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s %s' % (self.name, self.published)

class Comment(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    painting = models.ForeignKey(Painting, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    content = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    published = models.DateField()

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s %s' % (self.content, self.published)
```

And my resources.py looks like this:

```
from tastypie.resources import ModelResource
from api.models import Gallery, Painting, Comment
from tastypie.authorization import Authorization
from tastypie import fields
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class UserResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        queryset = User.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'user'

class GalleryResource(ModelResource):
    user = fields.ForeignKey(UserResource, 'user')

    #This does not work.
    paintings = fields.ToManyField(
        'self',
        lambda
        bundle: bundle.obj.painting_set.all(),
        full=True)

    class Meta:
        queryset = Gallery.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'gallery'
        authorization = Authorization()

class PaintingResource(ModelResource):
    gallery = fields.ForeignKey(GalleryResource, 'gallery')

    class Meta:
        queryset = Painting.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'painting'
        authorization = Authorization()

class CommentResource(ModelResource):
    painting_id = fields.ForeignKey(PaintingResource, 'painting')

    class Meta:
        queryset = Comment.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'comment'
        authorization = Authorization()
```

Answer (score 0):

The first argument of ToManyField is [to](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.io/en/latest/fields.html#to), the related model. So replace `self` with `PaintingResource`.  Also, the join will filter for related objects automatically, so the lambda is unnecessary.

```
paintings = fields.ToManyField(PaintingResource,
                               'paintings',
                               full=True)
```